# find the position of last occurrence of sub string in a string with limit of ending index

Tags: php, string

I have a string like

```
$string="abc @def @xyz $ @def @xyz";
```

Now i want to get index of last occurrence of @ before $.

Currently i am using

```
strrpos($string,'@');
```

Third parameter of strrpos will be starting index, can we give ending index?

Comment: Well again, just get the position of the last `$` sign as offset.

Comment: it will consider starting index of search i want index of @ before $.

Comment: what if the string would be `"abc @def @xyz $ @def @xyz  $ @bca"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `strrpos` you can get the last occurrence. More about [function.strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

For your purpose, you need to explode your string with `$` and start the application of `strrpos` for the first `index` of exploded array.

Try this:

```
$string="abc @def @xyz $ @def @xyz";
$strArr = explode('$', $string);
$pos = strrpos($strArr[0], "@");

if ($pos === false) { // note: three equal signs
    echo 'Not Found!';
}else
    echo $pos; //Output 9 this case
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:-

```
$string="abc @def @xyz $ @def @xyz";
$pos = strrpos($string, '@', -strrpos($string, '$')); 
if($pos === false){ 
    echo 'Not Found!';
}else{
    echo $pos; // 9
}
```

**Note**:- Negative sign will return index of last '@' before $ sign.

Comment: I find this solution a lot  more elegant, than exploding the string first